# Is there a way to make terminal commands require sudo in macOS Big Sur?

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-big-sur, bin

I'd like to prevent the use of the `osascript` terminal command by anyone without administrator access. I used to accomplish this by changing the permissions on the executable using `sudo chmod 744 /usr/bin/osascript`. The problem now (from what I understand) is that Big Sur does not allow changes to be made to the read-only system volume. I'd therefore like to find a workaround that retains this functionality ie. I don't want it to be possible to run this binary without the use of `sudo`. This has been a huge thorn in my side, and I don't want to have to resort to disabling SSV authentication in order to  edit the system volume. If there's any way to just elevate the permissions needed then that would be perfect.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's related to macOS and has nothing to do with programming . Asking on [su] or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit.

Comment: I'll be posting there as well as soon as I can (there seems to be a 40 minute posting limit on my new account). In the meantime, do you know of any way I can solve this?

Comment: Nope, but if I'm being honest, it sound more of an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) since `osascript` is available for each user by choice of the OS. Since the read-only changes, this became even more difficult, or maybe even impossible to alter.

Comment: I've taken a look at the link you sent on xy problems and I think I can provide some more clarification. Essentially I just want to prevent applescripts from being run by an administrator through a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly achieve it writing your [Endpoint security extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/endpointsecurity).

Subscribe to the ES_EVENT_TYPE_AUTH_EXEC and check the user from event parameters. Deny executing osascript from non root users.

It may sounds like a bit overkill, but there is no chance you can do it with SIP enabled in other way since big sur.

The only catch here is you need an apple developer account and request endpoint security entitlements from Apple. They could give it to you, if you desribe your solution in a proper way like security related project, but there are no guaranties.